# I want to make a Countries Combobox in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

i have a combobox in C#, does any body have a hard coded countries combobox code, having all the countries, so i can quickly paste it in my code.

Thanks a lot for help.
Atif

Comment: As an aside, I'd **never** recommend hard coding a list of countries, as the list will change over time, or even by country (as some countries are not recognised as a country by some other countries, at various times)

Comment: To be fair, I think it's quite clear what is being asked here.

Comment: @Ash: It is not a question. It is closer to a request I think. Don't you ? However, maybe it was more appropriate to close it as off-topic.

Comment: @Ash: Yes, it's clear what's being asked. But "give me teh cod3z" questions are considered "not real questions" here.

Answer (score 2):

[here.](http://www.textfixer.com/resources/country-dropdowns.php)

You might have solve this with a little bit google.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make a Countries Combobox in C#.net?

It's easy. Just grab a list of countries and make it the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx):

```
IList<string> countries = GetCountries();
comboBox.DataSource = countries;
```